# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS not recognizing my wifi router

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, network-manager

I am new to Ubuntu,in Wifi-networks I am able to see the routers of my neighbors,and some of them in near vicinity but it don't recognizes my WIFI router,I tried connecting it by clicking Connect to hidden networks but couldn't connect,

Everywhere I go be it my college or classes I am able to connect to the wifi facility avilable there but not in my home

I am using wired connection now, Its awful,anybody please help me in fixing this problem

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `iw reg get; iw list` terminal command`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what wireless card you have in your computer.. or what router you have, but some of the latest BT routers (and probably others) are using new encryption protocols that some older wireless cards/software simply don't support. you may be able to change the encryption system in your router by logging in using a wired connection, and then opting for older wifi encryption .. sorry i cant remember ffhand the names of the encrption protocols.. offhand.. but this solution worked for a friend of mine.. after changing it suddenly his wifi appeared in the list, and he was happy